# Echoing exit code in Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I've checked a few posts on SO, but not able to get the answer I want.

I want to run a Stata script as part of a Makefile. So in one of my targets, I define

```
live_data:
    @echo "Executing Stata code"
    StataIC -e 'stata_code.do'
    @exit_status=$?
    @echo "Finished execution of Stata code."
    @echo Code finished with exit code of $(exit_status)
```

However, whenever I look at the output of my `make all` command (which includes `live_data`), I see

```
Executing Stata code
StataIC -e stata_code.do'
Finished execution of Stata code.
Code finished with exit code of
```

Basically, the variable `exit_code` is always empty.

However, if I pop up a terminal and simply run `StataIC -e stata_code.do` followed by `exit_status=$?` and `echo $exit_status`, I get the correct result (0 or 1). Could someone point me to what exactly I'm missing here?

Comment: Each line is executed in its own shell. Just join them. I.E. terminate them by ;  and escape the eol with a \.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, as @AProgrammer has pointed out, each line in a recipe is executed in its own subshell, so a variable set in one line does not survive into the next:

```
trial:
    @var=blue
    @echo this command has no access to what was stored in var
```

The solution is to put the commands in one line

```
trial:
    @var=blue ; echo this command can use what was stored in var
```

and if that's too long, wrap the line with a backslash:

```
trial:
    @var=blue ;\
  echo this command can use what was stored in var
```

(Note that there is only one TAB, the one just before the `@`; the whitespace to the left of "echo" is just some spaces to make the rule easy to read.)

Second, you must be careful about the syntax. The way to expand a variable in Make is `$(var)`, but the way to expand it in a shell is `$var`; using either syntax in the other context will not give you the result you want.

```
var=red
$(info $(var)) # this is a Make command

trial:
    @var=blue ; echo this is a shell command, so $(var) will not work
```

Third, although a command in a rule is a shell command, Make will attempt to expand any variable it sees *before* running the rule, so we must escape the '$' in "$var" with another '$':

```
trial:
    @var=blue ; echo $var will not work, but $$var will
```

Put it all together and we get:

```
live_data:
    @echo "Executing Stata code" ; \
  StataIC -e 'stata_code.do' ; \
  exit_status=$$? ; \
  echo "Finished execution of Stata code." ; \
  echo Code finished with exit code of $$exit_status
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can simplify the recipe so that you don't need to save the value of `$?`.

```
live_data:
    @echo "Executing Stata code"; \
      StataIC -e 'stata_code.do'; \
      printf '%s\n' "Finished execution of Stata code." \
                    "Code finished with exit code of $$?"
```

Here, both strings are arguments to a single `printf` called immediately after `StataIC`, so `$?` correctly refers to the exit status of `StataIC`.